# What can cause this Login Failed Error?

Tags: sql-server

When I try to connect to SQL Server 2005 Enterprise edition on my local machine I get the below error:

"Cannot open user dafault database.Login failed.

Login Failed for user "Domain\My name"

What can cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SQl Server management studio try this

1. click the options button .
2. click the connection properties.
3. click on the Connect to database
4. type in the name of a database "master"
5. click connect.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Either the login's default database no longer exists, or the login has no rights to it. What version of SQL Server?

Comment: ... or integrated authentication is turned off.
Try connecting using SQL authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be because SQL Server is failing to contact the domain controller.

If it can contact the domain controller then Kerberos could be failing due to a skewed system clock or active directory not containing service principle names for the server.

You can check for Kerberos authentication errors in the system's event log.